# POST from inside Form

Tags: php, forms

how can I put value of text into the selector inside the form? I need to post text with **name=sum** into     `<option value="<?php echo $met->request; ?>"<?php if (isset($method) && $method == $met->request && $currentMethod = $met) { echo ' selected="selected"'; $shownext = true; } ?>><?php echo "$met->description - $met->full_summ $met->valute"; ?></option>`

This is my form

```
<form id="com_telecomax_buydid" action="

<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php',true); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return telecomax.complete;">

  <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_telecomax" />
  <input type="hidden" name="task" value="payment" />



 <h3> 
<?php if (isset($cart) && $cart) {?>
  <p><?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_TOTAL_COST_OF_YOUR_CART'); ?>:<span id="com_telecomax_payment_cart_text"><?php echo $cart.' '.JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_USD'); ?></span></p>
<?php } ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="cart"  id="com_telecomax_payment_cart" value="<?php echo isset($cart) && $cart ? 1 : ''; ?>" />

  <p><label for="com_telecomax_payment_sum"><?php echo JText::_($cart ? 'COM_TELECOMAX_ADDITIONAL_PAY_FOR_TALK' : 'COM_TELECOMAX_DEPOSIT_FUNDS'); ?>:</label>
  <input type="text" class="inp-txt" name="sum" id="com_telecomax_payment_sum" value="<?php echo isset($sum) && $sum ? $sum : $default; ?>" /></p>

  <p><?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_TOTAL_PAYMENT'); ?>:<span id="com_telecomax_payment_total">
   <?php echo isset($sum) && $sum ? $sum : $default; ?>
  </span> <?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_USD'); ?></p>
</h3>
  <p><input type="button" id="com_telecomax_payment_getmethod" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_GET_PAYMENT_METHOD'); ?>" />

  <p><label for="com_telecomax_payment_method"><?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_PAYMENT_METHOD'); ?>:</label></p>

  <p><select name="method" id="com_telecomax_payment_method">
    <option value=""<?php if (!isset($method) || !$method) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?> disabled="disabled"><?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_PLEASE_SELECT_PAYMENT_METHOD'); ?></option>
<?php foreach($this->methods['data'] as $item) { ?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $item['title']; ?>">
  <?php foreach($item['list'] as $met) { ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $met->request; ?>"<?php if (isset($method) && $method == $met->request && $currentMethod = $met) { echo ' selected="selected"'; $shownext = true; } ?>><?php echo "$met->description - $met->full_summ $met->valute"; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
    </optgroup>
<?php }
       ?>
  </select><input type="hidden" name="paysum" id="com_telecomax_payment_paysum" value="<?php echo isset($currentMethod) ? "$currentMethod->description@$currentMethod->full_summ@$currentMethod->valute" : '@@'; ?>" /></p>

  <p>
<?php if (isset($cart) && $cart) { ?>
    <input type="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_BACK'); ?>" onclick="location.href='<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_telecomax&task=cart',true); ?>'; return false;" />
<?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_TELECOMAX_NEXT'); ?>" id="com_telecomax_payment_next" style="display: <?php echo isset($shownext) ? 'block' : 'none' ; ?>;" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You are missing a second `=` on `&& $currentMethod = $met`. try - `if (isset($method) && $method == $met->request && $currentMethod == $met`

Comment: oh, ok, but what about post value

Comment: - $met->full_summ  I need to replace it with value of text name=sum from this form

Comment: I change it and have error now, so I don't have to add =

Comment: if this change of value is happening clientside, then can you not use PHP, but do you have to use JavaScript.

Comment: the error when changing to `$currentMethod == $met` is most likely because you are checking a variable `$currentMethod` against an object `$met`. shouldn't the `$met` be `$met->someotherthing`.

Comment: So you want to change `<?php echo "$met->description - $met->full_summ $met->valute"; ?>` to `<?php echo "$met->description - name=sum $met->valute"; ?>`? I don't really understand your question.

Comment: oh, I understand with $currentMethod = $met, it just should be inside if

Comment: I don't realy know javascript, something like this `$('input[name=myInput]').change(function() { ... });`